# javascript alert delete cookie else if don't delete cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, alert

I have made a button to delete a cookie that I have set, Its an alert with confirm.
On alert it says ok or cancel, if ok is clicked it reloads the page and deletes the cookie as it should.

But I dont want it to delete the cookie if cancel is clicked! Which it is doing?

Code to handle the alert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your score!");
        if (r==true)
        {
        alert("Your score has been cleared!");
        }
        else if(r==false)
        {
        window.location="javascript:history.go(0)";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Link to start alert and delete

```
<a class="restart" href="" onclick="deleteCookie('id8');">Clear score</a>
```

Comment: Just place the cookie deleting function under `r==true` part.

Comment: You don't need the if(r==false). With a boolean, it's true or false. Also, place the "document.cookie = name" before the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only remove the cookie is `r` is true:

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your score!");
    if (r) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        alert("Your score has been cleared!");
    }
    else {
        window.location="javascript:history.go(0)";
    }
}
```

Notice how I've moved that document.cookie line into the `if`? That way it'll only be run if the user hits the okay button. I've also refactored your logic code.

Comment: great let me know if you've any more questions about it :)

Comment: Is it possible to onclick deleteCookie (2 cookies)? I have tried the following but it only deletes id3? `onclick="deleteCookie('id3','correct3');`

Comment: sure. I'm about to have dinner, let me write something up afterwards :)

Comment: @DaisyOopsy This'll work nicely: https://gist.github.com/paterson/8303396 Notice how it takes in an array. That way you can delete an infinite amount of cookies. I've also changed the name of the function

Comment: That works perfectly, Thanks for your time, It has helped me understand the code better.